# python string indexout of range

Tags: python, string

I have written a code for checking if a 3-digit no. is an armstrong no.

```
x='371'
list1=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',]
s=0
L=len(x)
for i in range(0,L+1):
    if (x[i]==list1[0]):
        s=s+0
    elif x[i]==list1[1]:
        s=s+1
    elif x[i]==list1[2]:
        s=s+(2**3)
    elif x[i]==list1[3]:
        s=s+(3**3)
    elif x[i]==list1[4]:
        s=s+(4**3)
    elif x[i]==list1[5]:
        s=s+(5**3) 
    elif x[i]==list1[6]:
        s=s+(6**3)
    elif x[i]==list1[7]:
        s=s+(7**3)
    elif x[i]==list1[8]:
        s=s+(8**3)
    elif x[i]==list1[9]:
        s=s+(9**3)
print(s)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prasoon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Armstrongno..py", line 7, in <module>
    if (x[i]==list1[0]):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Expected output: in the end it should have printed the final sum s=371(because 371 is an armstrong no.)

Comment: It is not related to Java.

Comment: Sambit i know im new here and a tag is needed to ask question but the 'python' tag requires 1500 reputation so i wrote java

Comment: Creating a new tag would need 1500 reputation,  you can use the existing python tag. .. what's an Armstrong number?

Comment: You might get an answer to your problem but please rethink your algorithm. With `x` given the way it is I can calculate the sum in a one-liner with only 29 characters needed while having the flexibility of using numbers with less ore more digits than 3.

Comment: A tag requiring reputation means that it doesn't exist yet. Which in turn means you had a typo when trying to add the tag.

Comment: @BrainStone what do u mean by typo?

Comment: That you misspelled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your range of the loop is wrong,

why are you iteration till L+1?

```
L=len(x) # L=3
L+1 = 4 # you are trying to iterate till index 3, which doesn't exist
```

instead of:

```
for i in range(0,L+1):
```

use:

```
for i in range(0,L):
```

Comment: but the L shoud be equal to 3 length of x is 3 not 10

Comment: i know but...for loop will not iterate till (L)th iteration if the range is (0,L) that's why I set the range (0,L+1) so that it iterates till (L)th iteration because I want the program to traverse all the characters in the string 'x'